# What is the purpose manipulate method in layout.js?

Tags: uicomponent, magento2.2

I was searching a way to move around Magento 2 frontend components in the current page and stumbled across the following function in `module-ui/view/base/web/js/core/renderer/layout.js`

```
    manipulate: function (node) {
        var name = node.name;

        if (node.appendTo) {
            this.insert(name, node.appendTo, -1);
        }

        if (node.prependTo) {
            this.insert(name, node.prependTo, 0);
        }

        if (node.insertTo) {
            this.insertTo(name, node.insertTo);
        }

        return this;
    },
```

So I have set the appendTo property on a checkout component:

```
<item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="appendTo" xsi:type="string">shipping_container</item>
        </item>
    </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

I created shipping_container as a UI component and placed it somewhere on the page.

But nothing is happening (or moving to that place).

Does anybody know what is the purpose of the manipulate functionality? I did not find any uses of it in the core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this code using for moving component to specified parent element.

> I created shipping_container as a UI component and placed it somewhere
>   on the page.

Try to specify fullname of component which will be available by calling `registry.get`.

> I did not find any uses of it in the core.

Yes, as i can see magento core do not use this option in static xml files. But you can find this option in dynamic generated configuration `\Magento\Ui\Component\Layout\Tabs`

Comment: The name shipping_container is available in the registry. Still it does not work.

Comment: Update: It seems to work some how - checking `registry.get('shipping_container').elems()` shoes the element. But it does not seem to have a visual effect (element is not shown at that place)

Comment: hmm, maybe your container does not render childs?

Comment: Will check.  But it's also not removed from the old place.

Comment: as i can see `manipulate` add childs to parent, does not move from previous. I assume, that functionality for not-renderable components for insert child to other renderable components (existing code with tabs for example)

Comment: It worked. Turns out that my target component was not initialized properly at all because of `scope: checkout` instead of `scope:'checkout'`. I hide the source component by setting another displayArea so the move is complete. Only via XML :-) Pretty cool.

Comment: cool :) are component moved or copied to new target?

Comment: It's copied.  Not moved